# Unicode characters not working in preg_match_all

Tags: php, string, unicode, preg-match-all

I am trying to find number of occurrence of string in a file.But the file is full with sentences written in Unicode characters.

```
function probability($next,$now){
            $text_file = file_get_contents("temp/train_set.txt");
            $ans = preg_match_all("/\b$now $next\b/i", $text_file);
            echo $ans."<br>";
}
```

**$text_file** variable finds all the sentences and prints the unicode sentences just fine(I saw with echo).

**$now** and **$next** are two unicode strings.like $now="আমি" and $next="ভাত". Then the result is **0** ,but I have both strings together in my file.

**But whenever I put $now and $next two English string. It provides me the actual count. The problem occurs whenever I put unicode words in $now and $next.** I don't know maybe my question should be like 'how to make preg_match_all supports bengali unicode characters'

Ask me if you have any question.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `/u` flag (unicode):

```
$ans = preg_match_all("/\b$now $next\b/ui", $text_file);
//                              here __^
```

Comment: Thanks but now there is another problem with mix word. like English = "START" and "END" and Bengali Unicode "আমি" and "খাই" .Now If I put like this "আমি খাই" or "খাই END" --> OK. BUT "START আমি" --> NOT OK. I mean If I put english alphabet at the beginning , it does not count at all.

Comment: @NahidHossain: Remove the word boundaries `\b`